# Как добавить в представление контроллера ссылку на представление другого контроллера MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть модель тренера, клиента и модель персональной тренировки. Необходимо реализовать запись запись клиента на персональную тренировку.

```
[Table("Clients")]
public class Client : Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ФИО")]
    public string ClientFIO { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Отчество")]
     public string ThirdName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Дата рождения")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Пол")]
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Некорректный email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }       
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int Pasport { get; set; }
```

Модель тренера:

```
{[Table("Trainers")]
public class Trainer:Person
{
    [Key]
    public int TrainerId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Поле является обязательным к заполнению")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле является обязательным к заполнению")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Отчество")]

    public string ThirdName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Дата рождения")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле является обязательным к заполнению")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Пол")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле является обязательным к заполнению")]
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
    //[RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Некорректный email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле является обязательным к заполнению")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле является обязательным к заполнению")]
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле является обязательным к заполнению")]
    public int Pasport { get; set; }
    public TrainerSpecialization Specialization { get; set; }
    public Achievement Achievement { get; set; }
```

Модель персональной тренировки:

```
{[Table("PersonalTrainings")]
public class PersonalTraining
{[Key]
    public int TrainingId { get; set; }
    public string TrainerFIO { get; set; }
    public int TrainerId { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime TrainingDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime TrainingTime { get; set; }


    public bool IsWholeHour(DateTime d1)
    {

        string d2 = d1.Minute.ToString();
        string ss = "0";

        if (d2 != ss)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public bool IsOpen(DateTime time)
    {
        string stringTime = time.Hour.ToString();
        int hour = Int32.Parse(stringTime);
        if (hour < 7 || hour > 22)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Есть стандартная вьюшка Index, которая отображает список тренеров с возможностью редактирования, добавления и удаления. К этим ссылкам я хочу добавить "Записаться на тренировку"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, собственно, сама вьюшка ссылки записи на тренировку через контроллер тренера

```
@model FitnessClub.Models.PersonalTraining

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreatePersonalTraining";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PersonalTraining</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrainerFIO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainerFIO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrainerFIO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrainerId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainerId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrainerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubscriptionId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubscriptionId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubscriptionId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrainingDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainingDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrainingDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrainingTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainingTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrainingTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

Если я добавляю метод записи тренировки в контроллер тренера, то прописанные мною валидаторы не срабатывают, но тогда я не знаю как туда передать данные конкретного тренера. Если прописывать эти методы в родном (контроллер модели "Персональная тренировка") контроллере, то всё работает. ДАлее приведены сами методы:
1. Методы в контроллере тренера, который передаёт Id тренера и заполняет поля

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreatePersonalTraining(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Trainer trainer = db.Trainers.Find(id);
    PersonalTraining personalTraining = new PersonalTraining();
    personalTraining.TrainerId = trainer.TrainerId;
    personalTraining.TrainerFIO = trainer.LastName + " " + trainer.FirstName + " " + trainer.ThirdName;

    return View(personalTraining);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreatePersonalTraining([Bind(Include = "TrainingId,TrainerFIO,TrainerId,SubscriptionId,TrainingDate,TrainingTime")] PersonalTraining personalTraining,int? id)
{
    //var trainingsList = db.PersonalTrainings;
    Trainer trainer = db.Trainers.Find(id);
    var allTrainersTrainings = (from visit in db.PersonalTrainings
                     where visit.TrainerId == id
                     select visit);



    if (DateTime.Now.Date > personalTraining.TrainingDate.Date)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("TrainingDate", "Дата тренировки не может быть в прошедшем времени");
    }
    if (personalTraining.IsOpen(personalTraining.TrainingTime))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("TrainingTime", "Время работы клуба с 7 до 23");
    }

    if (personalTraining.IsWholeHour(personalTraining.TrainingTime))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("TrainingTime", "Введите целый час");
    }
    foreach (var item in allTrainersTrainings)
    {
        if (item.TrainingDate.Date == personalTraining.TrainingDate.Date && (item.TrainingTime == personalTraining.TrainingTime))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("TrainingTime", "Тренер занят");
        }

    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.PersonalTrainings.Add(personalTraining);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

В итоге программа даёт сохранить невалидные данные, хотя в процессе отладки всё работает верно.
ЕСли же прописывать эти методы в контроллере модели персональной тренировки (родном Create), то валидация работает, но я не знаю как передать эту ссылку на страницу со списком тренеров и данные тренера в это представление.

**Мои вопросы:**

1. Как добавлять на View контроллера ссылки на views других контроллеров, с возможность передачи данных (например, из списка тренеров (контроллер Trainers view Index ) передавать по индексу данные тренера в view создания персональной тренировки. Из-за непонимания/незнания ответа на этот вопрос, приходится писать методы в разных котроллерах. А может так и надо ? прошу прояснить принцип взаимосвязи контроллеров и их представлений, как передаются данные между ними.
2. Почему в описанном мною случае ( пример из вопроса 1 ) не отработали валидаторы ?

Comment: 1) Слишком много текста в вопросе, мало кто его дочитает 2) Вы задаете несколько разных вопросов в одном. То есть отвечающий должен ответить на несколько вопросов, а баллы заработать за один. Кому это интересно? Задавайте разные вопросы отдельно.

Comment: Мгм. В вопросе не указано, какие валидаторы не отработали. Навскидку - если не отработал DateTimeFormat то на enso такой вопрос неоднократно отвечали, я правдо давно на asp.net core ушёл, поэтому детально вряд ли буду ковыряться. Вопрос про принципы понятен, но я лично подожду пока вопросы будут разбиты. Код у вас очень близко вертится у правильного направления. Вот скажите - вы как себе представляете поле ввода тренера в тренировке - как <input type text или как <select`?

Comment: Ответ в двух словах. Валидация модели не являются частью ни того, ни другого контроллера - она должна находиться в модели. Если вам не хватает штатных валидаторов - пишите кастомные. Литература: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/7.6.php `[DateInPast]`, `[WorkingHours(From="7", To="23")]` и т.п. Можно даже ---грабить корованы--- в базу сходить при необходимости, пример быстро не нагуглился, а сам я такое уже давно не практикую, т.к. сильно перенёс всё на ajax.

Comment: А, вспомнил - атрибут Remote надо использовать.